# How can I destroy specifics $_SESSION variables leaving page?

Tags: php, session, pagination, get, unset

I would like to unset some specifics `$_SESSION` variables after leaving a page, but the problem is that I have used pagination (using `$_GET`) for all sections of my site (`contacts.php?page=1, ?page=2, etc; actions.php?page=1,?page=2 etc .; customers.php?page=1,?page=2,` etc ...).
For all the sections there are filters which, if set, are saved in some `$_SESSION` variables. Those variables must remain set when passing from `?page=1` to `?page=2` etc but it must be deactivated by switching from `contacts.php` to `actions.php`, otherwise in `actions.php` I will have the already setted filters that I had set in `contacts.php`!

Thanks!
PS Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

You can set the key name to null or ''.

For example

```
$_SESSION['key_name']='';
$_SESSION['key_name']=NULL;
```

Comment: if I do this, every time I pass from one page to another within the same session (contact.php? page = 1, contact.php? page = 2 etc) the filters I set are reset ... the filters must be reset only passing from one section to another (for example from contacts.php to actions.php) but not from one page to another of the same section

Answer (score 0):

sessions are recognized by a session id. if you delete this id the whole session (with all these entries) will be deleted. Therefore you could set the specific values to "null" and delete them this way.

you could do this either on the next page load or with javascript "on unload".

Answer (score 0):

To remove a session on some specific pages redirections pass some variable to the target page and check on that page if the key exists then use unset function

```
unset($_SESSION['key_name'])
```

In case you want to remove session completely use

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I know how to use unset() and session_destroy()...the problem is that if I insert these functions in the various sections, as soon as I pass from one page to another of the results within the same section (I'm talking about pagination), the filters I set and save in the variables $_SESSION['...'] are destroyed